# Rails AssociationTypeMismatch: Clan expected, got String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have an error `AssociationTypeMismatch: Clan(#92877230) expected, got String` when I try to seed my db.

I have 2 objects `Clan` and `Family` and I have a relation that `Clan` has_many Families, and `Family` belongs to Clan.

In my seed.rb I have a function like this:

```
Family.destroy_all
clans = Clan.all
clans.each do |clan|
  families.each do |family|
    clan.families.create(family) if clan.name == family[:clan]
  end
end
```

`families` is the array of hashes with all families that should be included.

From my search, I think that, when creating `family` it looks for a id of a clan.

I tried to add accepts_nested_attributes_for with the same error.

EDIT:

I done some testings and it looks like the clan, attribute of Family object is cousing the problem.

Here is the example of clan object from seed:

```
  {name: "Krab",
  clan_name: "Krab",
  mon_img: "",
  desc: "foo bar foobar"},
```

and here is the example of family object:

```
 { name: "Toritaka",
    clan: "Krab",
    desc: "some text....",
    bonus: "+1 Spostrzegawczość",  
    mon_img: ""},
```

I can create in console any clan.families as long as I don`t set clan attribute.

Comment: At which line the error is pointing to?

Comment: `   `clan.families.create(family) if clan.name == family[:clan]`

Comment: I done some test and the thing that couses the problem is the clan attribute of family object. I will update the question

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, the problem was caused by the `clan` variable in the Family objects. Don`t have any ide way, beside some name clashes.

Changing the name from 'clan' to 'clan_name' done the trick :)